# Unable to call a function while inside of a while loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I'm writting a simple program that writes out the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer on the wall. However, the function I've written to subtract one from bottlesNum does not work when I call it inside the while loop. I'm unsure what I've done here? Shouldn't I be able to call functions inside of while loops? I don't get an error when I run the code, the text prints over and over and bottlesNum always equals 99.

```
bottlesNum = 99

def bottle_subtraction(bottles):
    bottles = bottles - 1

while bottlesNum > 0:
    if bottlesNum != 1:
        print("{x} bottles of beer on the wall, {x} bottles of beer".format(x = bottlesNum))
    elif bottlesNum == 1:
        print("{x} bottle of beer on the wall, {x} bottle of beer".format(x = bottlesNum))

    bottle_subtraction(bottlesNum)

    print("Take one down and pass it around, {} bottles of beer on the wall".format(bottlesNum))
```

Comment: "Shouldn't I be able to call functions inside of while loops?" You are indeed calling it. I'm not sure, however, why you expect calling it to affect the global `bottlesNum`.

Comment: Your function essentially does nothing, you merely assign to a local variable the result of `bottle - 1`

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work if you do it like this:

```
bottlesNum = 99

def bottle_subtraction(bottles):
    bottles = bottles - 1
    return bottles # we return the updated value here

while bottlesNum > 0:
    if bottlesNum != 1:
        print("{x} bottles of beer on the wall, {x} bottles of beer".format(x = bottlesNum))
    elif bottlesNum == 1:
        print("{x} bottle of beer on the wall, {x} bottle of beer".format(x = bottlesNum))

    bottlesNum = bottle_subtraction(bottlesNum) # we store the updated variable

    print("Take one down and pass it around, {} bottles of beer on the wall".format(bottlesNum))
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to tell me why mine didn't work? The code works now but I'm unsure of how I went wrong with it.

Comment: @saeley The value got updated inside the function but because you never returned it and stored it back that change was never reflected outside your function. I updated my answer with some comments.

Comment: Your original code was in a different scope, so you were modifying the bottles in the `function` instead of the global bottles. This happens for assignments. You could tell the function to write to the global bottles if you use the `global bottlesNum` keyword

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
bottlesNum = 99

def bottle_subtraction(bottles):
    bottles = bottles - 1
    return bottles

while bottlesNum > 0:
    if bottlesNum != 1:
        print("{x} bottles of beer on the wall, {x} bottles of beer".format(x = bottlesNum))
    elif bottlesNum == 1:
        print("{x} bottle of beer on the wall, {x} bottle of beer".format(x = bottlesNum))

    bottlesNum = bottle_subtraction(bottlesNum)

    print("Take one down and pass it around, {} bottles of beer on the wall".format(bottlesNum))
```

The reason yours didn't work is because when you call the function, you don't return any value, all you did was give a reference.